# how to programmatically set an event location in android 2.3.3?

Tags: android

iam trying to add events to android calendar.I need to do it for android versions 2.3.3 to latest.so i have coded for version 4 and above separately and below 4 separately.The code is below.Its working for both well.But only problem is for version 2.3.3 location that i pass does not appear in the location field.So my question is **how to pass location to android's 2.3.3 calendar?**

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                        intent.putExtra("beginTime", beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
                        intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
                        intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
                        intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime.getTimeInMillis());
                        intent.putExtra("title", title);
                        **intent.putExtra("eventlocation", loc);**
                        intent.putExtra("description", desc);
                        intent.putExtra("hasAlarm", 1);
```

I have tried all these following alternatives but not working:

```
intent.putExtra("event location", loc);
intent.putExtra("Eventlocation", loc);
intent.putExtra("location", loc);
intent.putExtra("where", loc);
```

which is correct?plz help